# Add gestures to UISearchResults UITableView

Tags: uitableview, ios4, uisearchbar, ios5, uisearchresultscontroller

Currently my app has gestures, if you hold down on a UITableView cell you edit the object in the cell, if you tap the cell you view the object in the cell. That part works just fine but when the user uses the UISearchBar the results table does not have the same gestures.

Should I be adding the same gestures into else section of the initWithNibName?

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"AutoNotes2", @"AutoNotes2");
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
            self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
        }
        else {
            UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Concrete.png"]];
            [tempImageView setFrame:self.tableView.frame]; 

            self.tableView.backgroundView = tempImageView;
            self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.backgroundView = tempImageView;
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap)];

    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

    // Two finger, double tap
    UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerDoubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTwoFingerDoubleTap:)];

    twoFingerDoubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    twoFingerDoubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerDoubleTap];


    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.0; //seconds
    //lpgr.delegate = self;
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];

}
```